# Function in BYTE array straight to memory?

Tags: function, memory, virtual, byte

Is it possible to allocate virtual memory for a byte array containing a function, write the array in the memory and then somehow execute the function in virtual memory?

Comment: A “byte array containing a fuction” is an overly broad specification. What representation? What operating system? What hardware architecture? Your question cannot be answered without major clarifications.

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: C++. Windows. representation is in machine code(or what ever works). Both x86 and x86-64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be sure that the bytes you are going to execute are indeed a valid sequence of CPU instructions, or otherwise the "function" would definitely crash, such as causing exceptions "illegal instruction", "access violation" etc.

Next thing to do is to make sure that the bytes in question are located in memory that has a execution privilege. `VirtualProtect` with `PAGE_EXECUTE` get you that.

Then you are to actually pass control to your function. This can be assembly code, e.g. `push <address>; ret;` or C++ style call of static function with address in variable.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how I would call it with a static function using a pointer containing the address please?

Comment: Similarly to how you obtain function address via `GetProcAddress` API and cast it to the type you need. In your case this function entry point would be your data array.

Comment: What would I use in the hModule parameter? a handle of the current process?

Comment: You are missing the point here. Both you and `GetProcAddress` would get some pointer and use it as a function address/entry point. Such as "typedef VOID ( * FOO)(); FOO pFoo = (FOO) pnMyByteArray; pFoo();"